# How to click buttons by dragging mouse over them in swing?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I want to be able to click multiple JButtons with one mouse drag, but I can't seem to find any built in functionality to do this. I was considering just checking if the mouse drag crossed the coordinates of the buttons, but it seems like there should be a better way to do this. I am trying to make a program for designing poker charts where if you click on one of the buttons on the grid, they cycle between fold, call, raise, and all-in. The problem is that this is quite slow to do clicking one by one (since there's 169 possible hand combinations), and it would be nice to be able to click multiple at a time by dragging the mouse over them.

Comment: You would have to add a `MouseMotionListener` to all of the `JButtons` and check which buttons have had a mouse drag.  This seems like an odd GUI behavior to me.  Edit your question to explain what you're trying to accomplish and maybe we can suggest an alternative to `JButtons`.

Comment: I'm making a 13x13 grid where each button on the grid cycles between 4 options. I want to be able to drag my mouse of multiple buttons and click them at the same in order to make it a less time consuming process.

Comment: Not sure I'd make use of buttons for this case, I'd consider making a custom component which would otherwise achieve the result via a `MouseMotionListener` - but's the me

Comment: I'd probably use a drawing `JPanel` divided into 13x13 sections.  What are the four options for each section of the grid?  Posting a question on Stack Overflow shouldn't be a game of 20 questions.

Comment: I edited the post to include that information before I made my previous comment, Gilbert.

Comment: Okay, why do all 169 options have to be on one panel?  Can't you divide the options into multiple panels to not overwhelm the user?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a mouse listener which checks if the mouse is dragged across the buttons and then use [`button.doClick`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick-int-) to execute the button function or do a custom action.

Here's a simple program to demonstrate this

```
public class Main {

    private static final MouseAdapter adapter = new MouseAdapter() {

        boolean mouseDown = false;

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            if(mouseDown)
                ((JButton) e.getSource()).doClick();
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            ((JButton) e.getSource()).doClick(); // Click the initial button
            mouseDown = true;
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            mouseDown = false;
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JButton b1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("Button 3");

        b1.addMouseListener(adapter);
        b2.addMouseListener(adapter);
        b3.addMouseListener(adapter);

        b1.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println(((JButton) e.getSource()).getText()));
        b2.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println(((JButton) e.getSource()).getText()));
        b3.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println(((JButton) e.getSource()).getText()));

        JFrame jf = new JFrame();

        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jf.add(b1);
        jf.add(b2);
        jf.add(b3);

        jf.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3));
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```